# Different ways of updating bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

In gcp, I need to update a bigquery table  whenever a file (multiple formats such as json,xml) gets uploaded into a bucket. I have two options but not sure what are the pros/cons of each of them. Can someone suggest which is a better solution and why?

Approach 1 :

File uploaded to bucket --> Trigger Cloud Function (which updates the bigquery table) -->Bigquery

Approach 2:

File uploaded to bucket --> Trigger Cloud Function (which triggers a dataflow job) -->Dataflow-->Bigquery.

In production env, which approach is better suited and why? If there are alternative approaches,pls let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a broad question, so I wouldn't be surprised if it gets voted to be closed. That said however, I'd always go #2 (`GCS -> CF -> Dataflow -> BigQuery`).

Remember, with Cloud Funtions there is a max execution time. If you kick off a load job from the Cloud Function, you'll need to bake logic into it to poll and check the status (load jobs in BigQuery are async). If it fails, you'll need to handle it. But, what if it's still running and you hit the max execution of your Cloud Function?

At least by using Dataflow, you don't have the problem of max execution times and you can simply rerun your pipeline if it fails for some transient reason e.g. network issues.

Comment: Thank you v much @Graham. Do you have a link to any portal that explains these concepts in depth?